# How to create groups of like sounding names in R?

Tags: r, grouping, fuzzy-comparison, stringdist

I'd like to create a group variables based upon how similar a selection of names is.  I have started by using the stringdist package to generate a measure of distance.  But I'm not sure how to use that output information to generate a group by variable.  I've looked at hclust but it seems like to use clustering functions you need to know how many groups you want in the end, and I do not know that.  The code I start with is below:

```
name_list <- c("Mary", "Mery", "Mary", "Joe", "Jo", "Joey", "Bob", "Beb", "Paul")

name_dist <- stringdistmatrix(name_list)
name_dist
name_dist2 <- stringdistmatrix(name_list, method="soundex")
name_dist2
```

I would like to see a dataframe with two columns that look like

```
name = c("Mary", "Mery", "Mary", "Joe", "Jo", "Joey", "Bob", "Beb", "Paul")

name_group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4)
```

The groups might be slightly different depending obviously on what distance measure I use (I've suggested two above) but I would probably choose one or the other to run.

Basically, how do I get from the distance matrix to a group variable without knowing the number of clusters I'd like?

Comment: This question is probably too broad, but [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) might give you some ideas to get started with.

Comment: ...indeed some simple Googling leads one to the **stringdist** package, which might be helpful.

Comment: Indeed -- I must have just pasted part of my code-in.  The stringdistmatrix is a function in the stringdist package which generates distances among entries.  I was having trouble clustering by the distance after that but I think Huck below has provided a great example I can work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a cluster analysis like this:

```
# loading the package
require(stringdist);

# Group selection by class numbers or height 
num.class <- 5;
num.height <-0.5;

# define names 
n <- c("Mary", "Mery", "Mari", "Joe", 
       "Jo", "Joey", "Bob", "Beb", "Paul");

# calculate distances
d <- stringdistmatrix(n, method="soundex");

# cluster the stuff
h <- hclust(d);

# cut the cluster by num classes
m <- cutree(h, k = num.class);

# cut the cluster by height
p <- cutree(h, h = num.height);

# build the resulting frame
df <- data.frame(names = n, 
                 group.class = m, 
                 group.prob = p);
```

It produces:

```
df;
   names group.class group.prob
1  Mary         1          1
2  Mery         1          1
3  Mari         1          1
4   Joe         2          2
5    Jo         2          2
6  Joey         2          2
7   Bob         3          3
8   Beb         4          3
9  Paul         5          4
```

And the chart gives you an overview:

```
plot(h, labels=n);
```

[image]

Regards huck

Comment: There's no need for semicolons at the end of R statements (unless they're on the same line, of course).

Comment: Thanks, Huck for showing me how to implement the cluster analysis for a project like this one.  It seems like that will work with a little playing around!

Comment: @jlhoward Sorry for the semicolon routine. I'm an old limping man, who was drowned in the 90ties  in perl and pascal code ;-)

Comment: @huckfinn @Kath05: If you use the soundex method, the distance computed by `stringdist` is 0 if the two words translate to the same soundex code, and 1 otherwise. So you can get your name groups directly, using `name_group <- phonetic(name)`. (Of course this can't be applied to the other methods such as Levenshtein.)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `adist(...)` in base R to calculate the Levenshtein distances, and cluster based on that.

```
n<- c("Mary", "Mery", "Mari", "Joe", "Jo", "Joey", "Bob", "Beb", "Paul")
d <- adist(n)
rownames(d)  <- n
cl <- hclust(as.dist(d))
plot(cl)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  For what I'm doing, I like the ability to choose my distance methods which stringdist allows.  Depending on the list of names, I may group first by phonetic distance (soundex) and then by something else.  This is because I think some of the names I'm working with will be transliterated from a different language and alphabet.